# Zurb Foundation topbar downdown cutoff/clipped

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm setting up a new site using the topbar as my top navigation. I've got the code working on a blank page so I know the menu structure is correct, but when I integrate it into my site's design, the dropdown menus are cutoff/hidden behind the main content.

Not clipped:

[image]

Clipped:

[image]

Comment: Provide some code to allow for examination

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `overflow` is set (most likely to `overflow: hidden`) for either the topbar or one of its parents. Use the browser developer tools to examine the CSS for the topbar and its parents. Look for `overflow` style and disable it. If `overflow` is needed elsewhere, use more specific CSS selectors.